# add new column with the summary of all previous values (python)

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I am very new to python and trying to complete an appointment for uni. I've already tried googling the issue (and there may already be a solution) but could not find a solution to my problem.

I have a dataframe with values and a timestamp. It looks like this:

| created_at | delta |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1.45 |
| 2020-01-02 | 0.12 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1.01 |
| ... | ... |

I want to create a new column 'sum' which summarizes all the previous values, like this:

| created_at | delta | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1.45 | 1.45 |
| 2020-01-02 | 0.12 | 1.57 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1.01 | 2.58 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to define a method that I can use on different files (the data is spread across multiple files).

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```py
def sum_ (data_index):
    df_sum = delta_(data_index) #getting the data
    y = len(df_sum)   
    for x in range(0,y):
        df_sum['sum'].iloc[[0]] = df_sum['delta'].iloc[[0]]
        df_sum['sum'].iloc[[x]] = df_sum['sum'].iloc[[x-1]] + df_sum['delta'].iloc[[x]]

    return df_sum
```

For any help, I am very thankful.

Kind regards

Comment: You can use the cumsum() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```py
df['sum'] = df['delta'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df['y'] = df['x'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

output

```
   x   y
0  1   1
1  2   3
2  3   6
3  4  10
4  5  15
```